# What is latest(>9.6) postgres version fully compatible with Django 1.11.20?

Tags: django, postgresql, upgrade, compatibility, postgresql-9.6

Postgres 9.6 is deprecated, we need to upgrade to a version which is compatible with Django 1.11.20.

Django Docs mentions that any Postgres version(>9.3) should be compatible with Django 1.11.20.

Is there any way to verify that both versions are fully compatible and no code will break due to upgrade.

Note: we don't have much unit tests.

Comment: Isn't Django 1.11 end-of-life? Maybe look into upgrading that too. https://endoflife.date/django

Comment: Yes, this is in our future plans but right now we need to upgrade posgresql version only.

Comment: What if you just tried the new version in your staging environment?

Comment: Yes, we can try that, but currently looking for any supported compatible version which community might know.

Comment: I have a 1.11.x Django app running against Postgres 12.9.

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianKlaver for your input. This makes sense to us as v12.9 or before were released before the depreciation of Django 1.11.

Comment: FYI, I just did quick change to point at a Postgres 14.1 instance with Django 1.11 and it loaded and ran. The tests ran fine with exception of recent changes I have not updated tests for. Still I would probably do the move in steps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.