# compatibility between django version of 1.11.23 and postgres version of 13.8

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

My application uses django version of 1.11.23. I am thinking of switching the postgres version to 13.8, currently I m using 12.7 of postgres version. May I know if anyone faced compatibility issues while connecting django version 1.11.23 to 13.8 version of postgres

Comment: Since the last  [release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/1.11.29/) for Django was March 4, 2020 and the first [release](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for Postgres was September 24, 2020 I would say there could be incompatibilities depending on what you are doing. Per my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452768/what-is-latest9-6-postgres-version-fully-compatible-with-django-1-11-20) I did get Django 1.11 to run against Postgres 14 for my application, so there is hope.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply :), i will first upgrade in my local and test it thoroughly then